# Why does my new fixture keeps tripping the breaker?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a basic ceiling light in a room with a 3-way switch. I removed the existing fixture that was wired in the basic format (neutral-white, load-black, ground -bare). I replaced it with an ornate chandelier type fixture with multiple LED bulbs. Nothing in the instructions indicate a need for anything other than basic wiring. When I wired it up and tested the breaker tripped. The previous fixture worked with no issues. I even tried swapping the wires, since the fixture wires were unmarked, and it still tripped. Any thoughts on what's causing it to trip the breaker? My fear is that it's a short inside the new fixture.

Comment: Off hand I would think a ground wire is touching a hot wire screw.  Lights usually do not care about black and white, they work either way, just more safer for you to have the black on the centre post/not on the threads for the light.  Can also be the light is defective.

Comment: Thanks. There simply nothing to short out in my portion of the wiring. Connections are wire to wire with wire nuts. It's a super simple connection, which is what had me stumped. About decided it as to be the fixture. Even put the old fixture back to be sure it worked.

Comment: Is the breaker that trips a regular breaker or GFCI and/or AFCI? If it is GFCI and/or AFCI, what type of trip? (There should be a diagnostic code of some sort). Does it trip if you turn on the chandelier with no bulbs installed?

Comment: Including a picture of your wiring will help others to confirm that there's "simply nothing to shout out in my portion of the wiring". It's easy to miss your own mistakes because you're seeing what you expect to see. Others see what's actually there. I've written more than enough software code to know this is fact...

Comment: Assuming you live in the USA, is a lighting fixture that's tested to some well-known testing standard (such as UL or similar).  If this fixture is from Amazon or other online retailer and the fixture hasn't been tested and passed electrical standards and safety tests, then all bets are off on how safe the wiring is inside the fixture.  If the breaker doesn't trip when you don't have the light connected, and does trip when you do, then it's pretty obviously a problem with the fixture itself.